# Difference between = and :=

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm new to 6502 assembly programming and I'm using `cc65` suite (with C64 being the target). The official documentation indicates that `"The assembler accepts the standard 6502/65816 assembler syntax"` however I  have a hard time finding an authoritative reference. One thing I don't understand is the difference between the two assignment (?) operators in 6502 assembly `"="` and `":="`.

For instance in the file "c64.inc" we find

```
BASIC_BUF       := $200         ; Location of command-line
BASIC_BUF_LEN   = 89            ; Maximum length of command-line
```

Comment: Maybe [this reference](https://www.cc65.org/doc/ca65-6.html) could help?

Answer (score 4):

As @JoachimPileborg points out the `cc65` [documentation](https://www.cc65.org/doc/ca65-6.html) does explain it. The first operator `=` creates a symbol and assigns a given value to it. The second operator `:=` also makes the symbol a label. The names and values of labels are exported as a part of [debug information](https://www.cc65.org/doc/ca65-6.html#ss6.7) by the compiler (with the `-g` option), which is not the case with regular symbols. Consequently, it makes sense to use `:=`  to define memory locations and `=` for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

> **`:=` declares and assigns, `=` just assigns**

`:=` is a short form for declaration and initialization. wheres `=` is an assignment operator, used in the same way as another programming language.

```
x := 12
y := "value"
```

`x` is declared as `int` and initialized with value `12` where `y` is declared as `string` and initialized with the value `value`

```
var x = 12
var y = "value"
```

Comment: I have no idea why this answer has so many upvotes. This is not even `cc65` syntax.

Comment: @JeremyP its simple OP is asking for the difference and answer have an explanation

Comment: The answer is wrong. In `cc65`, the only difference between `:=` and `=` is that the former creates a label as well as a symbol i.e. the debugger knows about it nd treats it like an address label.